# How to make an array of hash from a hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I wish to convert the hash:

```
hash = { :c1 => "v1", :c2 => "v2", :c => "v" }
```

to an array of single-key hashes:

```
[{:c1=>"v1"}, {:c2=>"v2"}, {:c=>"v"}]
```

How can I do that? I tried

```
hash.each_pair { |c, v| [c, v] }
```

but that returns the original hash.

Comment: When you give an example in a question it must be a valid Ruby object. Yours is not, both because of the presence of `...` and the fact that none of the keys or values are defined. They are not literals so they can only reference variables or methods that are not defined in the question. You might instead write, for example, `h ={ :c1 => "v1", :c2 => "v2", :c => "v" }`. Notice that I assigned a variable to the hash. That is helpful so that readers can refer to it (`h`) in comments and answers without having to define it. As well, all answers will refer to the hash using the same variable.

Comment: You should edit your question to address the points I made in my comment above.

Comment: Why? A hash is easily manipulated and accessed, either in order or randomly. Your question sounds like an XY problem where you need to describe what you're trying to do, rather than ask how to do what you've decided is the right path. "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could it be: `hash.each_pair{|c, v| [k, v]}`

Almost. `each_pair` (or simply `each`) yields the pairs to the block and the block creates `[k, v]` objects. But `each` always returns the receiver (the original hash), so the new objects are discarded:

```
hash = { c1: 'v1', c2: 'v2', c3: 'v3' }

hash.each { |k, v| [k, v] }
#=> {:c1=>"v1", :c2=>"v2", :c3=>"v3"}
```

To get the objects, you can use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) – it returns the block's results as an array:

```
hash.map { |k, v| [k, v] }
#=> [[:c1, "v1"], [:c2, "v2"], [:c3, "v3"]]
```

And finally, to get hashes instead of arrays, you have to change `[k, v]` to `{ k => v }`:

```
hash.map { |k, v| { k => v } }
#=> [{:c1=>"v1"}, {:c2=>"v2"}, {:c3=>"v3"}]
```

Comment: I tried this but it still return the same result => a global hash.

Comment: @Fr33m1nd what do you mean "a global hash"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it doesn't come out splitted, nor in an array

Comment: `hash.map { |k, v| { k => v } }` returns the array of hashes I posted above. Maybe you need to _assign_ the result to a variable? e.g. `array = hash.map { ... }`

Comment: I tried again following your observations, I, now get an error message :
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: It should not be overlooked that `hash.map { |k, v| { k => v } }` tells the reader at a glance exactly what is being done.  Fr33, did you use Stefan's definition of `hash`? The one you gave in the question (`{c1 => v1, c2 => v2,  c => v}`) is not valid because none of the keys or values are literals. (Yes, they could be variables or methods, but those are not defined in the question, so I assume you intended them to be literals.) Stefan created literals for the keys and values in `hash`.

Comment: @Stefan I tried again following your observations, I, now get an error message :
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
I can't figure out why is this, there's no math involving pairs or so ... thanks for your help.

Comment: In this case the hash is defined like this:
```{"BTC"=>7028.14, "ETH"=>171.31, "XRP"=>0.188889,...}``` and the result should be 
```[{"BTC"=>7028.14}, {"ETH"=>171.31}, ...]``` @CarySwoveland

Comment: Fr33, `{"BTC"=>7028.14, "ETH"=>171.31, "XRP"=>0.188889,...}` is not a hash, as hashes do not contain `...`. If you mean `hash = {"BTC"=>7028.14, "ETH"=>171.31, "XRP"=>0.188889}`, `hash.map { |k, v| { k => v } } #=> [{"BTC"=>7028.14}, {"ETH"=>171.31}, {"XRP"=>0.188889}]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland By "..." I meant "etc" sorry for syntax. Mine is bad, yours is **good** ! This worked well for this example. _Thx_
Now I have to figure out how I close this question as it's my first time here.

Comment: Why close the question? If you found any of the answers helpful you can apply the green checkmark to the one you found most helpful. You should, however, also edit your question to address the points I made in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am spare on time right now, but this should do the trick.
Don't hesitate to ask some questions if desired, I will answer them later.

```rb
hash = {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo', foobar: 'barfoo', barfoo: 'foobar'}
hash.keys.map { |key| r = {}; r[key] = hash[key]  }
# => [{:foo=>"bar"}, {:bar=>"foo"}, {:foobar=>"barfoo"}, {:barfoo=>"foobar"}]
```

Comment: Please don't use answers to converse. Instead, an answer is just that, an answer; Use a comment to clarify. Remember, SO isn't a forum or message board, it's more like an online reference book.

Comment: I would have expected comments to come, and then I would have edited my answer to ad the clarification ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
a.map{ |i| Hash[*i]}
```

Above results in `[{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}, {:c=>3}]`

Comment: `to_a` is unnecessary here. I would also use more expressive names, like `hash` instead of `a` (`a` as in `array`?) and `pair` instead of `i` (`i` as in `index`?). `hash.map { |pair| Hash[*pair] }`

Comment: Make sense, We don't want `to_a`, Unnecessary iteration. Thanks.